# Tab page not displaying properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm having trouble with my html page, the tab pane A above displays the first pane correctly which is "SEARCH SOMETHING, SHOWING SOMETHING". But the problem is when i click the second tab, the "SEARCH SOMETHING, SHOWING SOMETHING" goes right on top of my tab pane B. I want it to display just the input box within the tab pane B. I dont want something like this:

> SEARCH SOMETHING
>   SHOW SOMETHING
>
> SEARCH ME
>   SHOW ME

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class"col-md-12" id="titleRectangular">
          <div class="tab-pane active in" id="a">
            <form class="form-search">
              <div class="input">
                <input type="text" name="search" class="search-input" id="search" placeholder="Search Something" style="width: 820px; height: 40px;" autocomplete="off" >
                <h4 id="result-text">Showing something: <b id="search-string">SOMETHING</b></h4>
                <ul id="result"></ul>         
              </div>  
            </form>
          </div>  
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
            <form class="form-search">
              <div class="input">
                <input type="text" name="search2" class="st-search-input2" id="search2" placeholder="Search Me" style="width: 820px; height: 40px;" autocomplete="off" >
                <h4 id="results-text">Showing me: <b id="search-string">B</b></h4>
                <ul id="results"></ul>          
              </div>       
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to wrap all your tab-panes into the `<div class="tab-content"></div>` block. You can use [this example from the Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#markup) as a template.
2. You have missed `=` in the line `<div class"col-md-12" id="titleRectangular">`.

Please check the result:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="col-md-12" id="titleRectangular">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active in" id="a">
              <form class="form-search">
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text" name="search" class="search-input" id="search" placeholder="Search Something" style="width: 820px; height: 40px;" autocomplete="off" >
                  <h4 id="result-text">Showing something: <b id="search-string">SOMETHING</b></h4>
                  <ul id="result"></ul>         
                </div>  
              </form>
            </div>  
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
              <form class="form-search">
                <div class="input">
                  <input type="text" name="search2" class="st-search-input2" id="search2" placeholder="Search Me" style="width: 820px; height: 40px;" autocomplete="off" >
                  <h4 id="results-text">Showing me: <b id="search-string">B</b></h4>
                  <ul id="results"></ul>          
                </div>       
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fade effect of your tabs isn't working because you're missing a wrapper for your tabs, specifically, a `<div>` element with the class `.tab-content`.

```
<div class="tab-content">
     <div class="tab-pane active in" id="a">
         <!-- Content of the tab with id="a" -->
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
         <!-- Content of the tab with id="b" -->
     </div>
</div>
```

Note that also the `<div>` element with the id `titleRectangular` in your code, was missing an equal sign for the classes of that element.

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="titleRectangular">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active in" id="a">
            <!-- Content of the tab with id="a" -->
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
            <!-- Content of the tab with id="b" -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, I noted in your code that the fade effect of your tabs isn't very smooth. The reason for that is you included the `.fade` class in one tab, but not in the other one.

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="titleRectangular">
     <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="a">
             <!-- Content of the tab with id="a" -->
         </div>
         <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
             <!-- Content of the tab with id="b" -->
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**See also**: [Bootstrap Tabs and Pills (W3Schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)

**Edit**: I include also the complete code, along with a Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/Oxcomw9nKA

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <br>
       <br>
       <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">    
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                   <li class="active"><a href="#a" data-toggle="tab">A</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#b" data-toggle="tab">B</a></li>
               </ul>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-12" id="titleRectangular">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="a">
                        <form class="form-search">
                            <div class="input">
                                <input type="text" name="search" class="search-input" id="search" placeholder="Search Something" style="width: 820px; height: 40px;" autocomplete="off">
                                <h4 id="result-text">Showing something: <b id="search-string">SOMETHING</b></h4>
                                <ul id="result"></ul>                                 
                            </div>      
                        </form>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="b">
                        <form class="form-search">
                            <div class="input">
                                <input type="text" name="search2" class="st-search-input2" id="search2" placeholder="Search Me" style="width: 820px; height: 40px;" autocomplete="off">
                                <h4 id="results-text">Showing me: <b id="search-string">B</b></h4>
                                <ul id="results"></ul>                                     
                            </div>                           
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>             
    </div>
</div>
```